# Excel How to extract two digits from Column A

Tags: excel

I have a question about **Excel** How Can I extract two digits from Column **B** if Column **B** is empty extract two digits from column **A**. I know how to extract two digit from Column **B** but cannot understand how to do it if column **B** is empty.

> for example: in column B in first row we have 123456 number we extract first 2 digits to column C, but in next row in column B is empty but column A is not empty and we need to extract number from column A.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the contents of the cells and extracts the digits if not blank

***C2***

=IF(B2="",IF(A2="","",LEFT(A2,2)),LEFT(B2,2))

Bye

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the =ISBLANK function along with an IF statement to check the specific column in B, if it is empty, take the value from A.